# Load text with variables in it and then print out

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, swift

I can print out the variable with \(variable) pattern

```
    let sayHello = "Hello"
    let contentA = "\(sayHello) bla bla bla"
    println(contentA) //output: Hello bla bla bla
```

Then I put the same string “\(sayHello) bla bla bla” in a text file and load it in to a variable, and then print it.

```
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("file", ofType: "txt")
    var possibleContent = String.stringWithContentsOfFile(path, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)

    if let contentB = possibleContent{
        println(contentB)
    }
    //output: \(sayHello) bla bla bla
```

The pattern \(sayHello) didn’t fetch the “sayHello” variable but just output literally.

I can print the class name with

```
    println("\(object_getClassName(contentB))")
```

It seems “contentA” is an instance of **_TtC10Foundation19_NSContiguousString**, and “contentB” is a **__NSCFString**.

How could I load some strings in a text file include output patterns like \(variable) and then replace them with REAL variables?

Actually, my ultimate goal is wrap up some HTML codes like “`<html><header></header><body>\(content)</body></html>`” and build them as a .html file.

Comment: Don't think you can do this. The string interpolation happens at the time the string literal is evaluated (i.e., when you assign `let contentA = ...`), not when it's printed. So loading from a file is like saying `let contentB = "\\(sayHello)"` -- you're just loading the actual characters.

Comment: An XML or JSON file is more closer to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually the compiler handling the string interpolation.  It turns the sequence `"Foo \(bar)"` into `"Foo " + bar.description`

For what you're trying to do you'll probably have to fall back to `+[NSString stringWithFormat:]` perhaps with positional parameters.